# macOS: How to open a local HTML file with URL parameters

Tags: terminal, applescript, google-chrome, url, chrome-extensions

I want to start a Kantu web macro [from the command line](https://a9t9.com/kantu/docs#cmd) on Mac. Essentially this is as simple as opening the Chrome or Firefox browser with a local HTML page (which contains the macro code). All works fine on Windows. But on macOS, when I use

```
mac:~ open 'file:////Users/fabrice/Kantu/demoautofill.html?direct=1&close=1&savelog=demotestlog.txt'
```

Chrome starts, and the file URL gets opened, **but** the `'?direct=1&close=1&savelog=demotestlog.txt'` GET parameter part is lost.

So the question is: How to launch a local html file with GET parameters?

I found this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7710803/open-a-local-html-file-with-url-params-through-applescript which uses AppleScript as a workaround, but it is for Safari, I need Chrome. Plus I would like to avoid using AppleScript, if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`open` just handles files, it doesn't know about GET parameters. So the AppleScript approach is probably the way to go here:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Google Chrome" to 
    open location "file:///Users/YOU/path/to.html?foo=bar"'
```

Comment: @cjk I have my default browser set to Safari, nevertheless the above snippet opens the page in Chrome.